# Entering values into an array, and then counting the # of unique values in it

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro that calculates the # of unique values within the column of a worksheet. There are a few other parameters as well, which I have covered already. Basically what I am trying to find out is how to input the values into an array ( unique () ), and then how to count the # of unique values into that array. This is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dateCheck As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim L As Integer
Dim I As Long
Dim shipDay As Date
Dim search As String
Dim unique() As Variant
Dim number As String

For L = 0 To 21  ' Execute code for whole month

    shipDay = Worksheets("June Canada").Cells(L + 10, 10).Text   'Sets to correct date

    For I = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count  ' Searches entire worksheet

        search = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 12).Value ' Checks for string within a row

        If ((InStr(1, search, "CAN", vbBinaryCompare) = 1) _
            And (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 8) = shipDay) _
            And (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 6).Text = "Invoice")) Then

            number = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 10).Value ' Set order number to variable

            ' Add the variable values to the dynamic array

        End If

    Next I

    Worksheets("JUNE canada").Cells(L + 10, 8).Value = ???  'Enter # of unique values into sheet

    shipDay = shipDay - L

Next L

End Sub
```

Comment: How about, check each one to see if it is in the array, and if it is NOT then add it to the array, After the whole sheet is read and all the unique values are loaded, just get the count of the array.

Comment: Good idea, I'll look up what that kind of code would look like.

Comment: To go along with what Chuck said its a double loop, Loop through all items, For Each item loop through Unique Array, if the item is found Exit For, if a Blank is found in the 2nd loop insert there and increment count by 1

Comment: Can't seem to figure this one out, as I am very new to arrays. Thanks for the help guys, I'll look for a different approach

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but it might need some adjusting:

```
' Add the variable values to the dynamic array
Dim foundIt As Boolean = False
For x As Integer = 0 To unique.Length
    If unique(x) = number Then
        foundIt = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If foundIt = False Then
    unique(unique.Length + 1) = number
End If
```